# Why bayesian needs prior and neural net does not?

Tags: bayesian, neural-networks, prior

Bayesian requires prior distribution that should be magically taken from somewhere.

Neural nets does not require that magical foreknowledge.

Why Bayesian requires it, why can't it work without it like neural net?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you perform Bayesian analysis *explicitly* you need to assume a prior; that is right. However, from a Bayesian perspective, there are many cases where you *implicitly* assume a prior distribution; for instance, the *regularization* term, $\lambda$, in [ridge regression](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Tikhonov_regularization) can be associated with normal distribution on parameters; or Lasso with Laplace distribution, etc. This is not restricted to linear regression. In many ML methods, Bayesian pespective associates regularization with some prior distribution over the model parameters. Neural networks are not an exception. For example, a neural net with cross-entropy loss + regularization can be thought of as log-likelihood + log-prior, as in MAP estimates.

Comment: Well put @gunes.  And note that the failure to use any prior information with machine learning _or_ statistical models means larger sample sizes are required for stability.

Comment: I think that this goes farther.  Many Bayesians would argue that you can't *not* have a prior.  Even if you do not have a regularization term, you are implicitly assuming an the [improper uniform prior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prior_probability#Improper_priors).  In other words, a neural net *does require a prior*.  However, the uniform prior is just the 'easy' prior, and so most models employ it whether they go so far as to say so or not.  If you want your Bayesian models to be without a prior, just replace the prior with a $1$.

Comment: @FrankHarrell "larger sample sizes...stability" -- Well, of course, if stability is what you're after, you could just use a prior with variance 0.  Then you only need a sample of size n=0 to train your model.  :)

Comment: Yes.  Bayes has extremely flexibility.  In the "large number of features" case most analysts would choose a horseshoe prior or other shrinkage priors in the absence of other knowledge.